# How to solve zensols.cli ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, git-clone

I have been trying to reuse the 'medsecid' code from Git Hub on VSCode. There inside the harness.py file, it is showing the following zensols.cli modeuleNotFoundError

> rebatching using 2 workers Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/fadiba/Desktop/medsecid/./harness.py", line 3, in 
> from zensols.cli import ConfigurationImporterCliHarness ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zensols.cli'

I have tried to install zensols.cli file with the command--
`pip install zensols.install`
But still, it is showing the above error.